# Getting info out of xml that has multiple feeds with XSLT

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, rss, items

Hi Everybody (Hi doctor nick!)

So I am having a little situation where I am stuck.
I am trying to create a file using XSLT and it won't seem to work.

First of let me tell you that I am using an XML file that is created by merging multple feeds.
Its structure is the following:

```
<sites>
<support>
    <rss>
        <channel>
            <title></title>
            <link></link>
            <description></description>
            <item>
                <link></link>
                <title></title>
                <description></description>
                <guid></guid>
                <pubDate></pubDate>
            </item>
        </channel>
    </rss>
</support>
<corporate>
    <rss>
        <channel>
            <title></title>
            <link></link>
            <description></description>
            <item>
                <link></link>
                <title></title>
                <description></description>
                <guid></guid>
                <pubDate></pubDate>
            </item>
        </channel>
    </rss>
</corporate>
```

Now. I managed to receive all the information (there are multiple items for each site) from one site but I want to get info from the other site too in the same template.

This is what I did:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="sites">
<xsl:text>CHNL 1002</xsl:text>
<xsl:apply-templates select="support/rss/channel/item"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="item">
<xsl:variable name="ms_title" select="/sites/support/rss/channel/title"/>
<xsl:variable name="ms_item_link" select="link"/>
<xsl:variable name="ms_item_title" select="substring-after(title, '/&gt;')"/>
<xsl:variable name="ms_item_date" select="pubDate"/>
<xsl:variable name="ms_item_description" select="substring-after(description, '/&gt;&lt;br /&gt;')"/>
<xsl:variable name="ms_item_image" select="substring-before(substring-after(description, 'src=&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
```

I can use the variables just fine for this site. But I want to use the corporate site in the same template. But I can't get the items from that one.
I tried some things but I end up with only the first item. but there are multiple items per site..

I've found variations of code to obtain info from feeds. but not from merged feeds within the same template. Is this even possible to achieve?

I tried the following:

```
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="sites">
<xsl:text>CHNL 1002</xsl:text>
<xsl:apply-templates select="support/rss/channel/item"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="item">
<xsl:variable name="ms_title" select="/sites/support/rss/channel/title"/>
<xsl:variable name="ms_item_link" select="link"/>
<xsl:variable name="ms_item_title" select="substring-after(title, '/&gt;')"/>
<xsl:variable name="ms_item_date" select="pubDate"/>
<xsl:variable name="ms_item_description" select="substring-after(description, '/&gt;&lt;br /&gt;')"/>
<xsl:variable name="ms_item_image" select="substring-before(substring-after(description, 'src=&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="corporate/rss/channel/item"/>
<xsl:variable name="rss_title" select="/sites/corporate/rss/channel/title"/>
<xsl:variable name="rss_item_link" select="link"/>
<xsl:variable name="rss_item_title" select="substring-after(title, '/&gt;')"/>
<xsl:variable name="rss_item_date" select="pubDate"/>
<xsl:variable name="rss_item_description" select="substring-after(description, '/&gt;&lt;br /&gt;')"/>
<xsl:variable name="rss_item_image" select="substring-before(substring-after(description, 'src=&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
```

But then I get the same info as the first site.

I hope I've been clear explainin gmyself. I'm not a good explainer type of guy.
And I hope someone has an answer for me! I would really appreciate it!
Thank you for your time reading this awful story of mine and i'm looking forward to try some new things!

Thanks!

Comment: I think it would help if you could show us your expected output. Also make sure your input example is well-formed; currently it is not.

Comment: I'm not a programming specialist so I don't really know what the hell I'm doing. It's mostly googling and trial and error.

What I am trying to achieve is obtaining the title, description, date and image of an item into an app I'm using. On the left I want to view the items from the first site and on the right I want to view the items from the second site. I would do a value select on the ms item variables, but I can't get a correct value select on the rss item variables.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="support/rss/channel/item"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//item"/>
```

then inside the template make sure you use relative paths so for instance

```
<xsl:variable name="ms_title" select="/sites/support/rss/channel/title"/>
```

becomes

```
<xsl:variable name="ms_title" select="title"/>
```